# alternative to jquery when

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, request

I know that we can use promise based http client like axios to use the then api like this

```
axios(url).then(success, error)
```

But If I want to send 2 simultaneous ajax requests, I will still have to restore to using jquery's $.when

```
$.when(promise1, promise2).then(success, error)
```

What is the alternative to $.when if I don't want to use a heavy library like jquery and use some lightweight lib.

Comment: Or code something on your own, it is not that hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise.all()`

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(success, error);
```

Comment: FYI: lacks IE support

Comment: And what library is going to give me the Promise object??

Comment: @Prabhas No library should be needed at browser. `Promise.all()` is available  at chrome, chromium 32+, firefox 29+, opera 19+, safari 7.1+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1):

Use $Q library: https://github.com/kriskowal/q
for your purpose you can use `$Q.all`

Comment: im not using angular

Comment: Its not angular dependent. Rather angular got its implementation using this library as core. You can run this in your desired browser and see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As our friend Rikin said above, using Q library is definitely a good choice. [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) doesn't continue the requests if any of those requests parameters fails.

Q have methods that makes this possible. Look, imagine that you have fn1 and fn3 that gives you HTTP 200 and fn2 returns HTTP 404, with this method `Q.allSettled` it will work perfectly.

```
Q.allSettled([fn1(), fn2(), fn3()])
.then(function(f1Result, f2Result, f3Result) {
   // your code that will run every time...
});
```

If you need to use it in your web project, follow these steps (you will need to have [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) installed in your machine):

1) Go to https://github.com/kriskowal/q and clone/download the repo.

2) Then to the folder where you cloned the repo and run `npm install`.

3) Finally, `npm run minify`. It will generate the q.min.js and you can use in your projects.

For more info, go to Q wiki reference: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference

Cheeers~